# Помогите решить проблему взаимодействия окон в PyQT5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Смысл в том что нужно чтобы окно№1 открывало окно№2, затем сведения из окна№2 передавались в окно№1. Открытие окон я настроил а вот с данными беда

Код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui, QtSql
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidgetItem
import menu, change, added
import sys, sqlite3

class my_window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, menu.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.ui = menu.Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(1)
    conn = sqlite3.connect('MO_MVD.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    table_row = 1
    row = 0
    for obj in cur.execute("SELECT * FROM MO_MVD"):
        self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(table_row)
        col = 0
        for item in obj:
            if item == None:
                item = ''
            if item == '1':
                item = 'ДА'
            if item == '0':
                item = ''
            cellinfo = QTableWidgetItem(str(item))
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(row, col, cellinfo)
            col += 1
        table_row += 1
        row += 1
    #self.ui.clr_btn.clicked.connect(self.add_row)
    self.ui.add_btn.clicked.connect(self.add_window)

def add_row(self):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('MO_MVD.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO MO_MVD VALUES ("","","","","","", "","")')
    conn.commit()
    table_row = 1
    row = 0
    for obj in cur.execute("SELECT * FROM computers"):
        self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(table_row)
        col = 0
        for item in obj:
            if item == None:
                item = ''
            if item == '1':
                item = 'ДА'
            if item == '0':
                item = ''
            cellinfo = QTableWidgetItem(str(item))
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(row, col, cellinfo)
            col += 1
        table_row += 1
        row += 1

def add_window(self):
    self.Added_Window = added_window()
    self.Added_Window.show()

def printed(self):
    self.ui.label_3.setText('Ghbdtn!')
    print('OK!')

class added_window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, added.Ui_add_window, menu.Ui_MainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.added = added.Ui_add_window()
    self.added.setupUi(self)
    self.added.save_btn.clicked.connect(self.add_item)
    self.added.cancel_btn.clicked.connect(self.cancel)

def add_item(self):
    self.zzz = my_window(self)
    self.zzz.setupUi(self)
    self.zzz.label_3.setText('123')

def cancel(self):
    self.close()
```

Comment: Добрый день! Не обижайтесь, но я убрал воду из вопроса :) Пожалуйста, отформатируйте код, отступы разъехались и код перестал быть рабочим. ЗЫ. названия классов в питоне принято с большой буквы называть: `my_window` -> `MyWindow` и т.д.

Comment: Насчет взаимодействия, тут я вижу два варианта. Первый самый простой -- сделать второе окно диалогом, т.е. от `QDialog` и работать с ним модально из главного виджета (для этого у виджета-диалога вызывать exec вместо show), тогда окно перекроет собой главное, вы в нем что-то сделаете и, после работы в этом окне, вернете данные, что должен получить главное окно (например через поля в этом виджете-диалоге). Второй вариант это через систему-сигналов слотов, тогда второе окно можно не делать модальным, но тут немного сложнее работать

Comment: Андрей, @gil9red вам дал максимально возможный ответ исходя из примера, который вы предоставили. Но вы должны понимать, чтобы получить ответ, содержащий работающий пример - вы должны предоставить [mcve]. Воспроизводимый - это значит, что ваш код копируется и запускается, а затем анализируется что у вас там происходит. Вы должны предоставлять все модули, в т.ч. и `menu.py`, `change.py`, `added.py`. Также правильно будет получить от вас скрипт, который БД с таблицами и данными, которые вы используете в приложении.

Comment: gil9red спасибо огромное Вам за участие! Как будет время я обязательно попробую Ваш совет :)